# How to read large xml file without loading it in memory and using XElement

Tags: xml, xpath, linq-to-xml, large-files, xelement

I want to read a large xml file (100+M). Due to its size, I do not want to load it in memory using XElement. I am using linq-xml queries to parse and read it.

What's the best way to do it? Any example on combination of XPath or XmlReader with linq-xml/XElement?

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can combine XmlReader with the [method XNode.ReadFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnode.readfrom.aspx), see the example in the documentation which uses C# to selectively process nodes found by the XmlReader as an XElement.

Comment: brilliant.  i'm developing an app that will be processing multiple 200M XML files and XDocument was killing me.  this has made a huge improvement.  thanks.

Comment: I think there's a bug in the example code on the `XNode.ReadFrom` documentation page. The statement `XElement el = XElement.ReadFrom(reader) as XElement;` should be `XElement el = new XElement(reader.Name, reader.Value);` instead. As-is, the first of every two 'Child' elements are skipped in the XML file from which it reads.

Comment: See my answer for code that works for me; see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2299683/173497) by [Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) for an explanation of why the two 'read' methods shouldn't be mixed. [Jon's answer doesn't mention the `XNode.ReadFrom` method explicitly, but I'm confident that the same issue applies.]

Answer (score 7):

The example code in the MSDN documentation for the `XNode.ReadFrom` method is as follows:

```
class Program
{
    static IEnumerable<XElement> StreamRootChildDoc(string uri)
    {
        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(uri))
        {
            reader.MoveToContent();
            // Parse the file and display each of the nodes.
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                switch (reader.NodeType)
                {
                    case XmlNodeType.Element:
                        if (reader.Name == "Child")
                        {
                            XElement el = XElement.ReadFrom(reader) as XElement;
                            if (el != null)
                                yield return el;
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> grandChildData =
            from el in StreamRootChildDoc("Source.xml")
            where (int)el.Attribute("Key") > 1
            select (string)el.Element("GrandChild");

        foreach (string str in grandChildData)
            Console.WriteLine(str);
    }
}
```

But I've found that the `StreamRootChildDoc` method in the example needs to be modified as follows:

```
    static IEnumerable<XElement> StreamRootChildDoc(string uri)
    {
        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(uri))
        {
            reader.MoveToContent();
            // Parse the file and display each of the nodes.
            while (!reader.EOF)
            {
                if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "Child")
                {
                    XElement el = XElement.ReadFrom(reader) as XElement;
                    if (el != null)
                        yield return el;
                }
                else
                {
                    reader.Read();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes.  The first example doesn't work.  It will read too much and skip every other "Child"

Answer (score 1):

Just keep in mind that you will have to read the file sequentially and referring to siblings or descendants is going to be slow at best and impossible at worst.  Otherwise @MartinHonnn has the key.