# Parse xml in c# : combine xmlreader and linq to xml

Tags: .net, xml, linq-to-xml, large-files, xmlreader

I have to parse large XML file in C#. I use LINQ-to-XML. I have a structure like

```
<root>
       <node></node>
       <node></node>
</root>
```

I would like use `XmlReader` to loop on each node and use LINQ-to-XML to get each node and work on it ?

So I have only in memory the current node.

Comment: What is your actual  question here?

Comment: @msarchet, I think the question is quite clear... he wants to use Linq to XML on each `<node>` element, but use `XmlReader` to obtain these elements, to avoid loading the whole document in memory

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linq To XML, yield and others](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957483/linq-to-xml-yield-and-others)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like that:

```
string path = @"E:\tmp\testxml.xml";
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(path))
{

    bool isOnNode = reader.ReadToDescendant("node");
    while (isOnNode)
    {
        var element = (XElement)XNode.ReadFrom(reader);

        // Use element with Linq to XML
        // ...

        isOnNode = reader.ReadToNextSibling("node");
    }
}
```

Comment: it works but on some case i have an error : Unable to cast object of type 'System.Xml.Linq.XText' to type 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement xmlreader. I don't know why so i make a test before cast (I test the node type). But i don't know if i lose results

Comment: @bobosh, I'm not sure what causes this problem... could you post a subset of your XML document that causes the problem to happen?

Comment: it's always the same template. Before i loop on node "node" with xdocument and i haven't the problem. On 2 thousand records i lose three records. nothing change on this records

Comment: well there must be *something* different about them, otherwise the behavior would be the same...