# How to parse very huge XML Files in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, parsing

I am working with dblp XML files. I actually want to parse the dblp.xml file and want to extract the usefull information for my further processing in some project. And that XML File is very huge (1.1 GB) and I am unable to even open this file.

Kindly guide me if you have C# parser for dblp.xml or you can guide me regarding this, or about how can we parse huge xml files.

Comment: XML parsing has been discussed _as nauseam_ on SO. Here's one such discussion that could enlighten you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55828/how-does-one-parse-xml-files

Comment: See XStreamingElement at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xstreamingelement.aspx as well.

Comment: Ryan Gates -> OSM files in XML format. This could be reason.

Comment: Had the same issue but realized that the code was compiled in 32 bits. After recompilation in 64 bits it was working fine. Of course it would be better to use the other approaches proposed such as XMLReader, but this simple trick may avoid to modify the code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use XML reader instead of XML dom. XML dom stores the whole file in memory which is totally useless:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx

Answer (score 8):

You need to use [`XmlReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx)

It represents a reader that provides fast, noncached, forward-only access to `XML` data. **Won't load all the data into memory**, supposed to be used with large sets of data. Other built in`.NET` solutions keep the full generated object graph.

[XmlReader in action (by Jon Skeet)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441673/reading-xml-with-xmlreader-in-c-sharp)