# How can I split large xml into small chunks using VTDGenHuge?

Tags: java, xml, vtd-xml

I want split large xml into small chunks. I am using VTDGen to split the xml file into small chunks and it works fine for file size < 2 GB. VTD-xml uses IN-Memory to parse the xml where i don't want to load the xml in to memory . So i am trying to map Memory using VTDGenHuge .

Code works fine with VTDGen but when i us VTDGenHuge it not working.

```
        String prefix = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n"+"\n";
    String suffix = "\n</Employees>\n";
    try {

        VTDGenHuge vg = new VTDGenHuge();
        if (vg.parseFile("C:\\Users\\abc\\Desktop\\latestxml\\Input_1.xml", true,VTDGenHuge.MEM_MAPPED)) {
            int splitBy = ;
           System.out.println("Started time"+ new Date());
            VTDNavHuge vn = vg.getNav();               
            AutoPilotHuge ap = new AutoPilotHuge(vn);
            ap.selectXPath("/Employees/Employee");
            FastLongBuffer flb = new FastLongBuffer(4);
            int i;
            byte[] xml = vn.getXML().getBytes();          
            while ((i = ap.evalXPath()) != -1) {  
                flb.append(vn.getElementFragment());
            }
            int size = flb.size();
            if (size != 0) {
                File fo = null;
                FileOutputStream fos = null;
                for (int k = 0; k < size; k++) {
                   if (k % splitBy == 0) {
                        if (fo != null) {
                            fos.write(suffix.getBytes());
                            fos.close();
                            fo = null;
                        }
                    }
                    if (fo == null) {
                        fo = new File("C:\\Users\\abc\\Desktop\\Test\\xml\\"+"out" + k + ".xml");
                        fos = new FileOutputStream(fo);
                        fos.write(prefix.getBytes());
                    }
                    fos.write("\n".getBytes());                       
                    fos.write(xml, flb.lower32At(k), flb.upper32At(k));
                }
                if (fo != null) {                       
                    fos.write(suffix.getBytes());                  
                    fos.close();
                    fo = null;
                }
            }

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I get NUll value at "byte[] xml = vn.getXML().getBytes();"
when u do syso vn.getXML() you get object value. but  with "getBytes()" return null.I don't no why. But if u do "byteAt(x)"  x = any long value it return value.

My  xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Employees>
<Employee id="1">
    <age>29</age>
    <name>Pankaj</name>
    <gender>Male</gender>
    <role>Java Developer</role>
</Employee>
<Employee id="2">
    <age>35</age>
    <name>Lisa</name>
    <gender>Female</gender>
    <role>CEO</role>
</Employee>
<Employee id="3">
    <age>40</age>
    <name>Tom</name>
    <gender>Male</gender>
    <role>Manager</role>
</Employee>
    <Employee id="1">
    <age>29</age>
    <name>Pankaj</name>
    <gender>Male</gender>
    <role>Java Developer</role>
</Employee>
<Employee id="2">
    <age>35</age>
    <name>Lisa</name>
    <gender>Female</gender>
    <role>CEO</role>
</Employee>
<Employee id="3">
    <age>40</age>
    <name>Tom</name>
    <gender>Male</gender>
    <role>Manager</role>
</Employee>
<Employees>
```

I want out put like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <Employees>
<Employee id="1">
    <age>29</age>
    <name>Pankaj</name>
    <gender>Male</gender>
    <role>Java Developer</role>
</Employee>
<Employee id="2">
    <age>35</age>
    <name>Lisa</name>
    <gender>Female</gender>
    <role>CEO</role>
</Employee>
<Employee id="3">
    <age>40</age>
    <name>Tom</name>
    <gender>Male</gender>
    <role>Manager</role>    
</Employee>
<Employees> 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Employees> 
    <Employee id="1">
    <age>29</age>
    <name>Pankaj</name>
    <gender>Male</gender>
    <role>Java Developer</role>
</Employee>
<Employee id="2">
    <age>35</age>
    <name>Lisa</name>
    <gender>Female</gender>
    <role>CEO</role>
</Employee>
<Employee id="3">
    <age>40</age>
    <name>Tom</name>
    <gender>Male</gender>
    <role>Manager</role>
</Employee>
<Employees>
```

Comment: Your code looks like C#.  You need to use a XMLReader.  You can search the web for c# xml huge.  Try this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15772031/how-to-parse-very-huge-xml-files-in-c

Comment: @jdweng  No it is not C#  it is JAVA code.

Comment: Doesn't look like JAVA, it is c#.

Comment: It looks like both :)

Comment: @ Vtd-xml-author it is purely java code. Copy past the code between  java main()  and  do the  changes required and run the code. it will run

Comment: We have updated the document for extended vtd-xml... on the web site or as a download as a result of your question.

Answer (score 1):

I think that vn.getXML() for extended vtd-xml returns a IbyteBuffer interface object **different** from standard vtd-xml. You can call the inteface method called **writeOutputToFile()** and pass to it the offset and value parameters.. sorry the documentation part of it is lacking, but that is the basic lowdown...

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        const int OUTPUT_ELEMENTS = 3;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            XmlReader reader = XmlTextReader.Create(FILENAME, new XmlReaderSettings() { IgnoreWhitespace = true });

            int count = 0;
            XDocument doc = null;
            XElement employees = null;
            reader.ReadToFollowing("Employee");
            while (!reader.EOF)
            {
                if (reader.Name == "Employee")
                {
                    if (doc == null)
                    {
                        string root = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" +
                                        "<Employees>" +
                                        "</Employees>";
                        doc = XDocument.Parse(root);
                        employees = (XElement)doc.FirstNode;
                    }
                    employees.Add(XElement.Parse(reader.ReadOuterXml()));

                    count += 1;
                    if (count % OUTPUT_ELEMENTS == 0)
                    {
                        doc.Save(string.Format(@"c:\temp\test{0}.xml", (int)(count / OUTPUT_ELEMENTS)));
                        doc = null;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (reader.Value == "")
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        reader.Read();
                    }
                }

            }
            if (doc != null)
            {
                doc.Save(string.Format(@"c:\temp\test{0}", (int)(count / OUTPUT_ELEMENTS)));
            }
        }
    }
}
​
```

Comment: The OP is using Java, not C#.