# Parsing 80 Gb XML File in c#

Tags: c#

I have to parse 80 GB OF XML to get some data from that file. I have used XML reader for this purpose. When I checked the code with 304 MB File. Then it parse the file within 4 sec. So I thought I will work for 80 GB. But it is giving me the memory out of exception after some minute.

I have the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<Test> lstTest = new List<Test>();
        bool isTitle = false;
        bool isText = false;

        using (XmlReader Reader = XmlReader.Create(FilePath))
        {
            Test tt = new Test();
            while (Reader.Read())
            {                    switch (Reader.NodeType)
                {
                    case XmlNodeType.Element:
                        if (Reader.Name == "title")
                        {
                            isTitle = true;
                        }
                        if (Reader.Name == "text")
                        {
                            isText = true;
                        }
                        break;
                    case XmlNodeType.Text:
                        if (isTitle)
                        {
                            tt.Title = Reader.Value;
                            isTitle = false;
                        }

                        if (isText)
                        {
                            tt.Text = Reader.Value;
                            isText = false;
                        }
                        break;
                }

                if (tt.Text != null)
                {
                    lstTest.Add(tt);
                    tt = new Test();
                }
            }


        }
    }
}
}
```

So Please suggest. Thanks For your help.

Comment: Can you check the size of `lstTest` object as you go through each iteration. I could be wrong, but I think `lstTest` is growing too big that its running out of memory.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15772031/how-to-parse-very-huge-xml-files-in-c

Answer (score 6):

You are correct, `XmlReader` is the right way to go. And it's not the `XmlReader` that is running out of memory - it's your `lstTest` where you shove most nodes that you find.

The correct way to use `XmlReader` would be to process the nodes and then forget about them, moving on. You can write the results to the disk, or calculate some running totals, or whatever - but don't keep everything you read in memory - that defeats the very purpose of `XmlReader`.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't store EVERYTHING into the memory, but only keep the parts that interests you.

This can be done via `IEnumerable<>` and the `yield return` keyword:

```
public IEnumerable<Test> ParseXml(string path)
{
    bool isTitle = false;
    bool isText = false;

    using (XmlReader Reader = XmlReader.Create(FilePath))
    {
        Test tt = new Test();
        while (Reader.Read())
        {                    
            switch (Reader.NodeType)
            {
                case XmlNodeType.Element:
                    if (Reader.Name == "title")
                    {
                        isTitle = true;
                    }
                    if (Reader.Name == "text")
                    {
                        isText = true;
                    }
                    break;

                case XmlNodeType.Text:
                    if (isTitle)
                    {
                        tt.Title = Reader.Value;
                        isTitle = false;
                    }

                    if (isText)
                    {
                        tt.Text = Reader.Value;
                        isText = false;
                    }
                    break;
            }

            if (tt.Text != null)
            {
                yield return tt;
                tt = new Test();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var data = ParseXml(/* your xml file */);

// select the part that you are interested in
var interestingTests = data
    .Where(x => x.Title == "...")

foreach (var test in interestingTests)
{
    // work with the interesting parts
}
```