# How to process extremely large .xlsx files with C#

Tags: c#, excel, memory-management

**Situation I need to solve**:

My client has some extremely large .xlsx files that resemble a database table (each row is a record, cols are fields)

I need to help them process those files (search, filter, etc).

**By large I mean the smallest of them has 1 million records.**

---

**What I have tried:**

- SheetJS, and NPOI: both libs only reply with a simple "file too large".
- EPPlus: can read files up to some hundred K records, but when faced with actual file it just give me a `System.OverflowException`, my guess is that it's basically out of memory, because a 200MB xlsx file already took me 4GB of memory to read.
- I didn't try Microsoft OleDB, but I'd rather avoid it, since I don't want to purchase Microsoft Office just for a job.

---

Due to confidentiality I cannot share the actual file, but you can easily create a similar structure with 60 cols (first name, last name, dob, etc), and about 1M records.

The question would be *solved* as soon as you can read an .xlsx file with that criteria, remove half of the records then write to another place without facing memory issue.

- Time is not too much of an issue. User is willing to wait an hour or 2 for result if needed.
- Memory seem to be the issue currently. This is a personal request, and the client's machine is a laptop capped at 8GB RAM.
- csv is *not* an option here. My client has .xlsx input and need .xlsx output.
- Language choice is preferably JS, C# for Python, since I already know how to create executable with them (well can't tell an accountant to learn terminal, can we?).

It would be great if there is a way to slowly read small chunks of data from the file row-by-row, but solutions I have found only read the entire file at the same time.

Comment: Save as uncompressed XML then read using the stream reader, [XmlTextReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15772031/how-to-parse-very-huge-xml-files-in-c). Storing as CSV should also work, assuming you pay attention to the encoding you select when saving in excel.

Comment: Thanks I'm checking the reader out. CSV doesn't seem to work, I did the conversion myself, and even though I specifically chose UTF-8 encoding, the result file still lose characters +_+

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For reading `Excel` file I would recommend [ExcelDataReader](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader). It does very fine with reading large files. I personally tried `500k-1M`:

```
using (var stream = File.Open("C:\\temp\\input.xlsx", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream))
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                var value = reader.GetValue(i)?.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Writing data back in the same efficient way is more tricky. I finished up with creating my own [SwiftExcel](https://github.com/RomanPavelko/SwiftExcel) library that is extremely fast and efficient (there is a performance chart comparing to other `Nuget` libraries including `EPPlus`) as it does not use any XML-serialization and writes data directly to the file:

```
using (var ew = new ExcelWriter("C:\\temp\\test.xlsx"))
{
    for (var row = 1; row <= 100; row++)
    {
        for (var col = 1; col <= 10; col++)
        {
            ew.Write($"row:{row}-col:{col}", col, row);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer**: Use any library that does not load sharedStringTable.xml file into RAM. I have seen many library but all load sharedStringTable into the RAM. So I have developed a one myself to solve this problem. Here is  [Source Code](https://github.com/ArjunVachhani/XlsxHelper) and [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/XlsxHelper/).

**Long Answer:** Xlsx file format is basically zip file that contains sheets in form of xml file. For the optimization purpose, Xlsx file stores duplicate cell value in a sharedString.xml file and refers the index of sharedString entry for duplicate cell value. Most of the library loads whole sharedString into a List/Dictionary for lookup purpose, and because of that processing large Xlsx files consume lot of RAM.

XlsxHelper takes a different approach. For small files it loads sharedString into RAM so that it can do lookup very fast. For larger file it indexes sharedString into a file and does a fileStream read, As a result for large file it takes very less RAM but it is slightly slower.