# XmlReader How to read properly?

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, treenode

what is the best way to read xml like this one:

```
<Users>
<user name = "mail">
    <supplier name = "supp1">
        <project name = "proj1">
            <subscribe name= "sub1"/>
            <subscribe name = "sub2"/>
        </project>
    </supplier>
    <supplier name = "supp2">
        <project name = "proj2">
            <subscribe name = "sub3"/>
        </project>
        <project name = "proj3">
            <subscribe name= "sub4"/>
            <subscribe name = "sub5"/>
        </project>
        <project name = "proj4"/>
    </supplier>
    <supplier name = "supp3"/>
            <supplier name = "supp5">
                 <project name = "proj4"/>
    <supplier name = "supp4"/>
</user>
</Users>
```

For now I am using

```
 While(reader.Read())
 {
    if (((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement) && (reader.Name == "user")))
     break;

            if ((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (reader.Name =="supplier"))
            {
                foreach (TreeNode tree in TreeView1.Nodes)
                {
                    if (reader.GetAttribute(0) == tree.Text)
                    {
                        TreeView1.SelectedNode = tree;
                        TreeView1.SelectedNode.Checked = true;

                        Get_projects(reader, tree);

                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

this is the main after that is get_projects(...):

```
private void Get_projects(XmlReader reader, TreeNode tree)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if ((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement) && (reader.Name ==  "supplier")) break;
                //(reader.IsEmptyElement && reader.Name == "supplier")
            if ((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (reader.Name == "project"))
            {
                foreach (TreeNode projTree in tree.Nodes)
                {
                    if (reader.GetAttribute(0) == projTree.Text)
                    {
                        TreeView1.SelectedNode = projTree;
                        TreeView1.SelectedNode.Checked = true;

                        Get_subscribes(reader, projTree);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

the  Get_subscribes(reader, projTree):

```
private void Get_subscribes(XmlReader reader, TreeNode tree)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
             if ((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement) && (reader.Name ==   "project") ||
                (reader.IsEmptyElement && reader.Name == "project")) break;
            if ((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (reader.Name == "subscribe"))
            {
                foreach (TreeNode subTree in tree.Nodes)
                {
                    if (reader.GetAttribute(0) == subTree.Text)
                    {
                        TreeView1.SelectedNode = subTree;
                        TreeView1.SelectedNode.Checked = true;

                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It doesn't work, so I am wondering is there a better way or what am i missing?

Comment: You need exactly XmlReader? Not XDocument nor XmlDocument?

Comment: Check out LINQ for XML.

Comment: Yep it has to be with XmlReader.

Comment: I just fixed it. The problem was the file could have <supplier name ".." /> with no elements inside, so I put a check if reader.isEmptyElement for supplier, project and subscribe.

Answer (score 0):

I will give you sample to read properly

```
<ApplicationPool>
    <Accounts>
        <Account>
            <NameOfKin></NameOfKin>
            <StatementsAvailable>
                <Statement></Statement>
            </StatementsAvailable>
        </Account>
    </Accounts>
</ApplicationPool>

static IEnumerable<XElement> SimpleStreamAxis(string inputUrl,                                          string elementName)
{
  using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(inputUrl))
  {
    reader.MoveToContent();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
      if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
      {
        if (reader.Name == elementName)
        {
          XElement el = XNode.ReadFrom(reader) as XElement;
          if (el != null)
          {
            yield return el;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(inputUrl))
{
    reader.ReadStartElement("theRootElement");

    while (reader.Name == "TheNodeIWant")
    {
        XElement el = (XElement) XNode.ReadFrom(reader);
    }

    reader.ReadEndElement();
}
```

Source: [Reading Xml with XmlReader in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441673/reading-xml-with-xmlreader-in-c-sharp)

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider the reverse approach i.e.: instead of reading XML and checking if a node exists in TreeView I would prefer to use XPath to check if a node exists in XML document.

In order to do so you have to traverse TreeView nodes and for each node build XPath query

> e.g.: /Users/user/supplier[@name='supp1']/project[@name='proj1'].

Having XPath query you can create an instance of XPathDocument based on your XMLReader and run the query. If something is found, you will check current node in TreeView.

Answer (score -1):

you can try XPath to read informations you need

```
XMLDocument doc = new XMLDocument();
doc.Load(your_xml_file_path);
XMLNodeList list = doc.SelectNodes(@"//project"); //get all project element
```