# Best Way to read XML Webpage

Tags: c#, xml, xamarin

Currently I am trying to use [Jon Skeet's method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441673/reading-xml-with-xmlreader-in-c-sharp) of parsing an XML webpage, however, this answer may be out of date and not the best way to do it in Xamarin.

```
public static IEnumerable<XElement> SimpleStreamAxis(string inputUrl, string elementName)
    {
        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(inputUrl))
        {
            reader.MoveToContent();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                {
                    if (reader.Name == elementName)
                    {
                        XElement el = XNode.ReadFrom(reader) as XElement;
                        if (el != null)
                        {
                            yield return el;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This request times out. Is this the best way to parse an XML webpage for Xamarin? If so, how do I fix the time out error that I am getting.

Comment: What resource? How are you calling it? What is the time out

Comment: Make sure to figure out what you have problem with - reading the page or parsing. So can't help you with resources returning errors/timing out. Additionally please try to clarify your criteria for "better" so one can suggest "the best" method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use htmlagilitypack to parse the document, and find the element through Xpath. if you want to download the webpage, you can use HttpClient module or htmlagilitypack's static methods