# Unable to load XmlReader into an XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml

```
<Response>
    <Items>
        <attributes></attributes>
    </Items>
    <Locations>
        <attributes></attributes>
    </Locations>
</Response>
```

I have an XML file in the format shown above.

I want to save `attributes` of parent `Items` in a separate table in the database and `attributes` of parent `Locations` in another table.

I am not able to use `XmlReader element .Read()`. I have been using `XmlDocument.Load` to initially load the reader as `XmlDocument` and by using 
`doc.SelectSingleNode("//Items")` will be selecting `nodes` and will parse through the inside information through `XmlReader` .

But now I am facing an issue in loading `XmlReader` into an `XmlDocument` as I get an `OutOfMemoryException.`

Can someone help me to solve this?

Comment: How big is the file?

Comment: I am not storing the xml as an file i get on a response from rest api . Size will be around 120MB.

Comment: I think you are going to have to work with the reader directly then to avoid having to load the complete document into memory.

Comment: only 120MB of data isn't enough for a `OutOfMemoryException`.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh `XmlDocument` uses around 10x the amount of memory as the source XML, so it'll be pretty close in an x86 process.

Comment: So what is the workaround how can i mangae it ?

Comment: @user3383301 Use the XmlReader to get the data you need.

Comment: I have the element  <attributes> with different parent element and both goes to different table . How do i differentiate ?

Comment: Depending on how your larger XML is structured, the hyrbrid 'streaming' approach in the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441673/reading-xml-with-xmlreader-in-c-sharp) may be appropriate.