# convert XML into array list..C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml

i have a XML string

```css
<Role name="Admin">
    <PermissionName>ViewEmployees</PermissionName>
    <PermissionName>EditEmployees</PermissionName>
</Role>
<Role name="HR Manager">
    <PermissionName>Shifts</PermissionName>
    <PermissionName>ViewShifts</PermissionName>
    <PermissionName>AddShifts</PermissionName>
    <PermissionName>DeleteShifts</PermissionName>
</Role>
```

want to convert it into array list..please help.

Comment: It is surprising that there are no existing questions on this topic... In any way please explain why you need ArrayList as result?

Comment: to get roles and permission  in list .   string[] roles= ,,string[] permissions=..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does one parse XML files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55828/how-does-one-parse-xml-files)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading Xml with XmlReader in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441673/reading-xml-with-xmlreader-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
testString = "<root>" + testString + "</root>";    
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(testString));
var arrayList = doc.Descendants("Role")
                .Select(a => new Role{
                    Name = a.Attribute("name").Value,
                    Permissions = a.Descendants("PermissionName").Select(x=> x.Value).ToList()
                }).ToArray();


public class Role{
public string Name{get;set;}
public List<string> Permissions{get;set;}
}
```

Is this what you are looking for??

Comment: i got an issue There are multiple root elements. in line 1
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(testString));

Comment: The xml string doesn't have a root element. Is this xml coming from a different source? If not surround it with a root element

Comment: yes  not surround it with a root element.

Comment: testString = "<root>" + testString + "</root>"; Add this line before creating the XDocument