# Get Value from XML File

Tags: xml

i want to extract a value from an XML File and i already saw some solutions but i couldnt find one that works for me.

Here is my Sample XML File (**i want to extract the Serial Number**)

```
<Other TrashCodeSample="SampleTextHere">
    <Data key="SerialNumber">911987082611993854940173</Data><Data key="TrashNumber2">5346587345345</Data></Other>
```

I already got some Code but it only gives me the last Value in **"Data"**

```
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(label3.Text);

            var authors = doc.Descendants("Data");

            foreach (var author in authors)
            {
                textBox1.Text = (string) author;
            }
```

the Serial Number is the Value i want to get:

```
<Data key="SerialNumber">911987082611993854940173</Data>
```

- if Possible i want to Edit the Serial Number inside the XML

---

it would be easy if i only had one "Data" but thats not the case.. :/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading Xml with XmlReader in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441673/reading-xml-with-xmlreader-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use LINQ and C# then try `doc.Descendants("Data").First(d => (string)d.Attribute("key") == "SerialNumber")` to access that `data` element. You can then read out or set its `.Value` property.

Comment: do you have an idea how i can modify the Serial Number?

Comment: I wrote you can set the `.Value` property so `doc.Descendants("Data").First(d => (string)d.Attribute("key") == "SerialNumber") = "1234567890";` modifies the contents of that `data` element. You will then have to call the `doc.Save("newfile.xml")` method to save back to a file.