# Can't send a stream file with httpClient to web api

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, httpclient

i tried to send a basic file from my integration test project in C# to a web api .
But i don't know why, each call i get an exception .

***Json.JsonSerializationException : Error getting value from 'ReadTimeout' on 'System.Io.FileStream'***

I found this property can't be read , so maybe that why my httpclient can't serialize it.
So how can i send a file to a web api ?

**This is my code from the client:**

```
using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText("SaveMe.xml"))
{
    response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync($"api/registration/test/", reader.BaseStream);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
}
```

**And my controller:**

```
[Route("api/registration")]
public class RegistrationController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost, Route("test/")]
        public ActionResult AddDoc(Stream uploadedFile)
        {
            if (uploadedFile != null)
            {
                return this.Ok();
            }
            else
            {
                return this.NotFound();
            }

        }
```

Here the screenShot we can see , the property [ReadTimeout] can't be access.
[image]

Comment: I suspect you can't use the `FileStream`. You can also check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10320232/how-to-accept-a-file-post

Comment: Ok i will check that tonight

Comment: Sorry, but i can't find some help from your your link :-(  Is not explain how to send a file with httpCLient  , by the way . I update my post. My controller wait for a [Stream] and not a [FileStream]

Comment: @MehdiBugnard confirm which version of asp.net-mvc you are using. asp.net-core or asp.net-web-api?

Comment: Looks to me like you're sending XML and saying it's JSON. That doesn't sound like it would work.

Comment: XML file is not the problem, if i change with a text file, it's still not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if they still support `PostAsJsonAsync` in .NET Core, which I am on. So I decided to rewrite your snippet as follows using `PostAsync`:

```
    using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText("SaveMe.xml"))
    {
    var response = await client.PostAsync($"api/registration/test/", new StreamContent(reader.BaseStream));                                   
    }
```

Update your API method to look like:

```
[Route("api/registration")]
public class RegistrationController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost, Route("test/")]
    public ActionResult AddDoc()
    {
        //Get the stream from body
        var stream = Request.Body;
        //Do something with stream
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to read all the data from file and only then send it. To open the `.xml` files use `XmlReader`. look here [Reading Xml with XmlReader in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441673/reading-xml-with-xmlreader-in-c-sharp)

Comment: If i try with a (Text File) the problem still remaining