# Why is XmlReader skipping tags?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xmlreader

XmlReader is skipping tags and I have no idea why. If you execute the code below you'll see the ID 123 and 789 being printed out meaning 456 was skipped. If you run the alternative memory stream which uses 1234 you'll see only 123 and 456 printed meaning 1234 and 789 being skipped.

Here's the main piece. Complete code below. I create an XML reader with a stream, I have a while loop, I check for the depth I want (because the nodes aren't at depth 0). `XElement.ReadFrom(root) as XElement` from my understanding reads XML until the tag closes which is what I want. Then I simply print out the id value. It's simple enough and less than 10 lines of code

```
var root = XmlReader.Create(fs);
root.MoveToElement();
while (root.Read())
{
    if (root.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement || root.Depth != 1)
        continue;
    var el = XElement.ReadFrom(root) as XElement;
    Console.WriteLine(el.Attribute("id").Value);
}
```

If I put newlines between `</node><node>` it won't skip the tags but that feels like a bandaid and I'm not sure if my input will have newlines after `</node>` or not.

---

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace nearMe
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var fs = new MemoryStream(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?><test><node id=""123"">
        <tag k=""amenity"" v=""fuel"" />
    </node><node id=""456"">
        <tag k=""name"" v=""B"" />
    </node><node id=""789"">
        <tag k=""amenity"" v=""test"" />
    </node></test>")))
            {
                var root = XmlReader.Create(fs);
                root.MoveToElement();

                while (root.Read())
                {
                    if (root.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement || root.Depth != 1)
                        continue;
                    var el = XElement.ReadFrom(root) as XElement;
                    if (el == null)
                        continue;
                    if (el.Name != "node")
                        continue;

                    Console.WriteLine(el.Attribute("id").Value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
using (var fs = new MemoryStream(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
    <test>
        <node id=""123"">
            <tag k=""amenity"" v=""fuel"" />
        </node>
        <node id=""1234"">
            <tag k=""amenity"" v=""fuel"" />
        </node>
        <node id=""456"">
            <tag k=""name"" v=""B"" />
        </node>
        <node id=""789"">
            <tag k=""amenity"" v=""test"" />
        </node>
    </test>"
)))
```

Comment: You could have noticed that every second element was skipped. Beside that I suggest that you read nodes by their name if you know the node name. Makes reading much easier IMHO.

Comment: The reason you are not getting all the element is due to getting the first node you are then at the second node and then are moving to the next node skipping the second node.  My solution checks if you are at a node so you do not move.

Answer (score 1):

Your bug is pointed out in a comment for a similar question:

> Calling [`XElement.ReadFrom`] reads the element and goes to the next one, then the following [`root.Read()`] reads the next one again. You'd essentially miss an element if they happen to have the same name and be consecutive.
>   ([pbz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441673/reading-xml-with-xmlreader-in-c-sharp#comment8181903_2441694))

The simplest way to fix this is to eliminate the `ReadFrom` and continue getting values from the reader:

```
            while (root.Read())
            {
                if (root.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Element || 
                    root.Depth != 1 ||
                    root.Name != "node")
                    continue;

                Console.WriteLine(root.GetAttribute("id"));
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using (var fs = new FileStream("test.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    var test = XElement.Load(fs);
    var nodes = test.XPathSelectElements("node[@id]");

    foreach (var node in nodes)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(node.Attribute("id").Value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use code below.  It doesn't skip and uses xml reader.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

             using (var fs = new MemoryStream(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?><test><node id=""123"">
                            <tag k=""amenity"" v=""fuel"" />
                        </node><node id=""456"">
                            <tag k=""name"" v=""B"" />
                        </node><node id=""789"">
                            <tag k=""amenity"" v=""test"" />
                        </node></test>")))
            {
                XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(fs);

                while (!reader.EOF)
                {
                    if(reader.Name != "node")
                    {
                        reader.ReadToFollowing("node");
                    }
                    if(!reader.EOF)
                    {
                        XElement node = (XElement)XElement.ReadFrom(reader);
                        int id = (int)node.Attribute("id");
                        Console.WriteLine(id.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```